# How to split list by certain repeated index in python

Tags: python

I have this list of decimal values

```
[97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112] // more and more...
```

How to split it in this way :

```
[[97,98,99,100],[101,102,103,104],[105,106,107,108],[109,110,111,112]]
```

then convert the decimal values to string so it can be like this

```
['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop']
```

Comment: Decimal values? They seem to be ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```
a = [97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112]
[''.join(chr(j) for j in a[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(a), 4)]
```

Output:

```
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
```

Comment: Perhaps simplify to `[''.join(chr(j) for j in a[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(a), 4)]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested generator (list) comprehension for a one liner:

```
base = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
        105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]

y = ["".join((chr(k) for k in j))for j in (base[i:i+4]for i in range(0, len(base), 4))]
```

```
>>> y
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
```

---

If you are using `floats` (decimals) cast to int with this:

```
y = ["".join((chr(int(k)) for k in j))for j in (base[i:i+4]for i in range(0, len(base), 4))]
#                 ^^^
```